# What should I do about Hebrew Language questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, hebrew

Questions specifically about the Hebrew language are [off topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on Mi Yodeya. So, where can I ask questions only related to the Hebrew Language?

Answer (score 7):

There is currently an Area51 proposal in Commitment Phase specifically for that express reason:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Hebrew Language]

Because it's in the Commitment Phase now, you can't ask questions at this moment. However, if you commit to the proposal, you will be counting towards the total number of 200 committers that are required to bring the proposal into the Beta Phase. (If you have at least 200rep on this site or another SE site, extra credit for counting towards the 100 experienced committers.)

Once the proposal reaches 100% Commitment, the Private Beta, a portion of Beta where you can't get in to the site without an SE account, begins.
Soon afterward Private Beta, the Public Beta will open, giving access to anyone who wants to view, ask, and answer questions about the Hebrew Language.